# How to randomly pick one of multiple hostnames under one alias (~/.ssh/config)

Tags: ssh, hostname

Is it possible to make ssh pick a random IP address (using a wildcard) to connect? We have 30 computers with IP addresses from "asd**1**.asd.asd.asd.com" to "asd**30**.asd.asd.asd.com", and i want to connect to one of them (randomly selected) using the alias xxxx. Is there a simple way to do this using the ~/.ssh/config file?

I've tried to use this wildcard:

```
Host xxxx
Hostname asd[0-30].asd.asd.asd.com
User my_username
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: If you are trying to do a load balancing, doing it from the client side, is not the way to go. Just a thought. And I don't believe ssh, internally is able to do such a thing. You can do something like `num=$(( ( RANDOM % 30 )  + 1 )); ssh asd${num}.asd.asd.asd.com` and alias it to something like `myssh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really had to, you could do something like this:

```
Host xxxx
     User my_username
     ProxyCommand nc asd$((1+$((RANDOM %% 30)))).asd.asd.asd.com 22
```

This assumes you're using the bash shell -- otherwise you can put the proxy command as the argument for a bash invocation, e.g.

```
     ProxyCommand /bin/bash -c "exec nc asd$((1+$((RANDOM %% 30)))).asd.asd.asd.com 22"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ssh itself can do it.

You can do it with dns if you assign all the IP numbers to one host name in some zone you control.

Another option is to write a simple wrapper (for example in Python) that calls ssh with a random selected address.